# SharedPreferences not saving all the data after restart

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences

I am new to Android App Development and I am supposed to make a TodoList App for a course. But the SharedPreference in my code is not working. I dont know if I'm supposed to use it in a specific way in a specific method like onCreate or onStop.

It is saving the first input the user is entering permanently, but in the same position:
[image]
(The *"task0"* is what I used to track the different variable names I used as argument for **"putString"** in **addStuff** method, to avoid replacing values)

It is saving the inputs after that in the same session, but if the user ends that session, all those values after "t" are gone. If the user restarts the app and inputs something else (like "g"), it is saving "g" in that same 3rd position.

I have basic Java knowledge and I tried to understand what is going on using it, but failed. Please let me know where is the mistake and how to use SharedPreferences properly.

```
public class TodoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public ArrayList<String> items;
public ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter;
public ListView list;
public String s;
public EditText taskBox;
public static final String filename = "itemsList";
public TextView text;
public static int counter = 0;//counter starting at 0 no matter what, everytime the app starts
public String newtask= "task";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_todo);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    taskBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.box);
    s = taskBox.getText().toString();

    items = new ArrayList<String>();

    itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    list.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

    //add items to list
    items.add("First Item");
    items.add("Second Item");

    //restore
    SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("itemsList", 0);

    //checking if it stores the previous values, this gives the last input but not the previous ones after restarting the app
    String dummyname = "task";
    text.setText(String.valueOf(counter));//since counter is again at
    for(int c=0; c<=50; c++){
        String num = String.valueOf(c);
        dummyname = dummyname + num;
        String x = sp.getString(dummyname, "not found");
        if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("not found")){
            counter=c-1;
            break;
        } else {
            items.add(x);
            text.setText(dummyname);
        }
    }

}

public void addItem(View v){
    s = taskBox.getText().toString();
    itemsAdapter.add(s);//adding the new task as string

    String temp = String.valueOf(counter);
    newtask = "task" + temp;

    //trying to store the new tasks with different variable names to avoid being replaced
    text.setText(newtask);
    SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("itemsList", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();
    e.putString(newtask,s);
    e.apply();

    counter++;
}
```

}

Comment: Where did you get value from shared preference?

Comment: try using `e.commit()` after finishing add your data.

Comment: I tried it. Didn't work. @ישואוהבאותך

Comment: When the user is clicking the add button, the addItem method is called. In that method, I'm saving the data the user entered in the textbox. That is where the value is coming from, which I want to save permanently as a new item for the list. @Smartiz

Comment: You were getting wrong values from shared preferences. See my answer. @SamaSamrin

Answer (score 1):

If you have relatively small collection of key-values that you would like to save,
You should use [Shared preference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) API

**Read from the shared preference:**

Pass the key and value you want to write,create a SharedPreferences.Editor by calling edit() on your SharedPreferences.

Pass key and values you want to save by using this method    **putInt()** ,**putString()** ,Then call **commit()** to save the changes. For example:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("KeyName", newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

**Write from the shared preference:**

To retrieve values from a shared preferences file, call methods such as **getInt()** and **getString()**,
providing the key for the value you want, and optionally a default value to return if the key isn't present. For example:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt("KeyName", defaultValue);
```

Comment: I got this basic idea, and implemented it this way but, after I close the app and restart it, the values go away too. 
After adding items.add(x); in onCreate(), it is saving the first input in the 3rd position of the list (after "First Item" and "Second Item") but not the later ones. Also, it is saving all the inputs in that 3rd position only. 
I don't understand why.

Comment: Basically it will replace your old value with update values so you will not got a previous value. /

Comment: oh. so if I want to save each new input as a new irreplacable list item, what should I do?

Comment: Convert your save object into String format like "Json" or better to make a database .

Comment: Do you think is it helpful answer for your question . Please mark as accept. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 0):

Two things :

1) To initialize SharedPreferences use :

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("itemsList", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

2) Where are you calling `addItem()` method??

Comment: addItem is being called as the method when the ADD button is clicked, in the xml.

Comment: and I used your first suggestion initially, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about the Tag you use to save items. See this Line :

```
dummyname = dummyname + num;
```

You add item by this format :

```
task0
task1
task2
```

but you are getting values in this format

```
task0
task01
task012
```

Just change these two line of code :

```
//dummyname = dummyname + num;
//String x = sp.getString(dummyname, "not found");
String newDummy= dummyname + num;
String x = sp.getString(newDummy, "not found");
```